# How do I move all arguments entered in a shell script to a folder?

Tags: bash, shell, command, arguments

I am trying to move all the arguments that are given when the script is run, to a `RecycleBin` directory. I am setting `RecycleBin` to be a directory in my home folder using `RecycleBin="$HOME/Recycled"`.

I then want to move all the arguments files / directories to the `RecycleBin` directory.

This is what I've got so far:

```
for  i in $* 
do
if [ $* -e ]
then
mv $i /path/to/RecycleBin/$*.`date +"%Y%m%d.%H%M%S"`
else
echo "The file does not exist"
fi
done
```

where `.date +"%Y%m%d.%H%M%S"` is appending the version `(date command)` of each file

and `for  i in $*` is checking for all the arguments in the command.

Output will look something like this ./script.sh file1 file2 file3 
- where 3 files are being moved into `RecycleBin`

This is not working as my loop function is incorrect.

Would appreciate help

Thanks
Pete

Answer (score 2):

```
[ $* -e ]
```

That test should be this:

```
[ -e "$i" ]
```

Also in the `mv` command you should be using `$i` rather than `$*`. Personally I'd just get rid of the `if` statement entirely. `mv` will print out an error message if a file doesn't exist, no need to do it yourself.

To handle file names with spaces in them it's best practice to use `"$@"` in place of `$*`, and to surround your variable names with with quotes, like so:

```
for file in "$@"; do 
    mv "$file" "/path/to/RecycleBin/$file.$(date +%Y%m%d.%H%M%S)"
done
```

Comment: @user2232423 It's basically a whitespace-safe version of `$*`. See the [bash(1) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) for specifics.

Comment: @user2232423 I'm guessing the first three errors are coming from elsewhere in your script since nothing you've posted has the words "specified", "repetitive", or "shown". The `mv` error is telling you that the directory `/path/to/RecycleBin` does not exist.